How to make text that a normal user can see by hovering over an image accessible to robots?
How to make text that a normal user can see by hovering over an image accessible to robots?


It probably already is accessible, assuming it's just html and css, though it may not be as prioritised as content that's visible without any user interaction.
What code are you currently using? How do mobile users access this information?

I'm looking at the webcache version of the page https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://tile.expert/en-gb/catalogue/equipe&strip=1 and I realise that robots don't see the text from the pop-ups that appear when you hover over images. Mobile users cannot access this information right now but in the future it will be visible by clicking on the question mark.

If you view the source (link at top of cache view), then you can see it in the alt text, and if I search for specific text then your site comes up.  Indexing seems fine.
